# Apache 403 Forbidden error only on some machines

Tags: apache, http, http-status-code-403

Been trying to figure out how and why this error appear on some machines (not all). Tried it on my home pc and it worked, my boss tried it on his home pc and the error appeared, he also tried it on his laptop and that worked, also some clients also experience error and some don't. The server administrator said he hasn't changed the configurations for years and I did not change anything in the scripts. This error appeared only recently. Does anyone know what might cause it?

Comment: How should we know why authorization of requests against your system are denied? Do you expect us to somehow magically guess how you authenticate and authorize such requests without you posting any code or configuration here? Sorry, we are good, but we are not _that_ good.

Comment: What are the access rules on the server?